# collision doesn't work in render (it works well when I play a preview before rendering!)

Tags: rendering, particles, collision

I'm trying to make some balls fall on a cube and not to fall through it. everything works well after I set the stickiness to 10, but in the render result the balls go though the cube (I'm using blender 2.8 and tried EEVEE and Cycles render but both don't work)

I've tried working around all the settings in render, particles and collision taps but non of them worked.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15raTLSHrNdrHV4JisVEibkTBwESCAWwb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Tested your file -> if you *bake it* before rendering, the particles stick to the geometry (how to bake it is explained in the linked answer above): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XQE4.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful!